# Do any European politicians advocate shutting down American bases in Europe?

Tags: european-union, donald-trump, military

The USA has military bases all over the world (including in some EU countries such us Germany, Italy, Spain, Portugal and Greece) which is expensive to their economy. [List of military bases here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_military_bases) On 11/06/2018 Donald Trump complained about the fact that USA is protecting Europe at a high expense.

[image]

If the European parliament is working to create a much more united Europe and UK is meant to leave in the next months. Are there any remarkable European politicians who advocate to shut down all American bases in Europe?

Comment: Upon re-reading this Q I think that the Euro-Army thing has to get its own Q. Otherwise I read here two Qs, both quite broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes. The German party [*The Left*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Linke#Au%C3%9Fenpolitik)  ("Die Linke", 69 seats of 709 in the federal parliament elected 2017) does call for a closure of all US-bases on German soil (and bases of any other country as well)

> - Vom Boden der Bundesrepublik Deutschland aus dürfen keinerlei militärische Drohneneinsätze in anderen Ländern koordiniert oder geleitet werden. Die militärischen Standorte in Deutschland, die derzeit an solchen Drohnenkriegen beteiligt sind – wie Ramstein, das AFRICOM und das EUCOM – müssen geschlossen werden.
> - Alle ausländischen Militärbasen in Deutschland müssen geschlossen werden. Entsprechende Verträge, auch mit den USA im Rahmen von Aufenthaltsvertrag und dem Zusatzabkommen zum NATO-Truppenstatut, werden gekündigt. Die Infrastruktur in der Bundesrepublik darf nicht genutzt werden, um völkerrechtswidrige Kriege und menschenrechtswidrige Maßnahmen wie die Verschleppung von Gefangenen zu ermöglichen.
>     Source: official press release from [Die Linke, XV. Nein zum Krieg. Für eine demokratische und gerechte Welt](https://www.die-linke.de/wahlen/ablage-bundestagswahlen-2017/wahlprogramm/xv-nein-zum-krieg-fuer-eine-demokratische-und-gerechte-welt/)

Translation:

- No military drone operations in other countries may be coordinated or conducted from the territory of the Federal Republic of Germany. The military sites in Germany currently involved in such drone wars - such as Ramstein, AFRICOM and EUCOM - must be closed.
- All foreign military bases in Germany must be closed. Corresponding contracts, also with the USA within the framework of the residence contract and the supplementary agreement to the NATO troop statute, are to be terminated. The infrastructure in the Federal Republic of Germany must not be used to enable wars that violate international law and measures that violate human rights, such as the abduction of prisoners.

They also advocate a complete dissolution of the whole of NATO and replacing that with a new collective security architecture that includes Russia ([Official party programme, English version, 2011, p70](https://www.die-linke.de/fileadmin/download/grundsatzdokumente/programm_englisch/englisch_die_linke_programm_erfurt.pdf).). But this position is one of the reasons why they are nowhere near getting into power in the foreseeable future. All other parties in parliament are much more hawkish and often cite this position as evidence that "this party" would not even be able to form or contribute to any government.

Comment: Do they have any English language resources? Specifically more about the proposed collective security architecture.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt They have an English version of their  page at https://en.die-linke.de/welcome/, but the search on that directly seems broken now… Maybe via another search engine?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt [This](https://en.2017.die-linke.de/news/detail/stop-powerplays-halt-war-danger/) and the [currently official programme](https://www.die-linke.de/fileadmin/download/grundsatzdokumente/programm_englisch/englisch_die_linke_programm_erfurt.pdf)

Comment: The question is if politicians of this party count as "remarkable European politicians", given that they are far from ever getting to power.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main positions of the **Communist Party of Greece (KKE)** is for Greece to leave NATO and all US military bases in Greece to be closed.

Greek communists are against any imperialistic intervention and has often demonstrated against the decision of NATO to use Greece as strategic passage for military operations & exercises in the Balkans,Syria,Afghanistan et.al, ex. [KKE demo denies NATO passage in Salonica](https://inter.kke.gr/en/articles/The-KKE-and-the-anti-imperialist-movement-are-intensifying-the-struggle-against-NATO/)

Also, it has [created alliances](http://icp.sol.org.tr/europe/communists-greece-and-turkey-rise-against-nato) with other Communist parties to join forces against US intervention in an international level.